# toggle custom sorting icon in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have been trying to put a custom grid style and sorting icon in angular js and have succeded to do so far also except for the toggling of sorting icon

here is my html code of headers

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TableCtrl">

        <table class="MmTable">
            <thead class="TblRow HeaderRow">
                <tr>
                    <th class="TblHeader TblHeaderSortable SortIndex0 Column0" style="text-align: left;">
                        <i ng-click="sort('Subsidiary',$event)" class="SortDesc">
                            Subsidiary
                            <span class="{{Header[0]}}"></span>
                        </i>

                    </th></theah></table>
```

and here is sort function

```
$scope.sort = function (sortBy,event,element) {
    $scope.resetAll();

    $scope.columnToOrder = sortBy;
    $scope.sortingOrder = 'asc';
    //$(element).removeClass('SortDesc');
    //$(element).addClass('SortAsc');

    //$Filter - Standard Service
    $scope.filteredList = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredList, $scope.columnToOrder, $scope.reverse);

    if ($scope.reverse)
        iconName = 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up';
    else
        iconName = 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down';


    $(this).removeClass('SortDesc');
    if ($(this).hasClass("SortDesc")) {

        $(this).removeClass().addClass('SortAsc');


    } else {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('SortDesc');
    }

    if (sortBy === 'Subsidiary') {
        $scope.Header[0] = iconName;
    }
    else if (sortBy === 'name') {
        $scope.Header[1] = iconName;
    } else {
        $scope.Header[2] = iconName;
    }

    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

    $scope.pagination();
};
```

as, in above code i was trying to manipulate dom then found that cant do that in Angular.
so,tried witg ng-style also but didn't work.
Just needed a bit help in toggling of sorting icon as i want to put custom class for asc and desc sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could toggle some [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) icons like this...

HTML:

```
<tr ng-controller="toggleController as tc">
  <th ng-click="tc.toggle('name')">Name
    <i ng-class="tc.nameDesc ? 'fa fa-toggle-down' : 'fa fa-toggle-up'"></i>
  </th>
  <th ng-click="tc.toggle('date')">Date
    <i ng-class="tc.dateDesc ? 'fa fa-toggle-down' : 'fa fa-toggle-up'"></i>
  </th>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module("toggleApp", []).controller('toggleController', function () {
  this.toggle = function (property) {
    this.nameDesc = (property === 'name') ? !this.nameDesc : this.nameDesc;
    this.dateDesc = (property === 'date') ? !this.dateDesc : this.dateDesc;
  }
});
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bholben/7tLejvr2/).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to keep a boolean variable in your scope, lets say sortAscending="true", when you sort in descding order change the value to false.

In your html you can use something like this

```
ng-class="sortAscending ?'ascClass':'desClass'"
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uev10oru/

Adding new working example with toggle button
http://jsfiddle.net/uev10oru/1/

Comment: still not the correct way giving lexixal error if i do like this 
ng-class="{'SortAsc' : sortAscending()}",then its fine but ternary operator causing problem

Comment: you might have mixed single/double quotes, refer a working example http://jsfiddle.net/uev10oru/, change true to false to see change

Comment: here is my snippet <i ng-click="sort('Subsidiary',$event)" ng-class="sortOrder ? 'SortAsc' : 'SortDesc'" >still giving that lexical error

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60140/discussion-between-user3631413-and-coder).